# Spring Envers conditional update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-envers

I'm using Spring boot with Spring Data and Hibernate 5 Envers. 
It's works fine. I wan't to ignore updates based on the contents of a field (e.g. status). I have followed this [guide](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/conditional-auditing-hibernate-envers/) and hibernate's official documentation. However, when I try to implement EnversPreUpdateEventListenerImpl it is not found. I have included envers in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have EnversPreCollectionUpdateEventListenerImpl and similar classes available, which makes me think that my approach is wrong. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step here is to determine what listeners you need to override.  It sounds like from your question that you've determined that.

The first thing I recommend is provide Hibernate with `hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners` config property set to `false`.  This makes sure when the default `EnversIntegrator` is called, it skips the event registration preventing the default listeners from being attached to the `SessionFactory`.

The next step is to basically *copy* the `org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator` code to a custom class.  You can obviously exclude the listener opt-out check because your custom implementation won't need that check.  What you will need to change are the few lines where the listeners are being registered and instead register your own rather than the default ones.

For example

```
if ( enversService.getEntityConfigurations().hasAuditedEntities() ) {
  // ...
  listenerRegistry.appendListeners( 
    EventType.PRE_UPDATE, 
    new MyCustomEnversPreUpdateEventListener( enversService )
  );
}
```

Where `MyCustomEnversPreUpdateEventListener` would look something like this

```
public class MyCustomEnversPreUpdateEventListener 
  extends EnversPreUpdateEventListenerImpl {
  @Override
  public void onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
    final String entityName = event.getPersister().getEntityName();
    if ( getEnversService().getEntitiesConfigurations().isVersioned( entityName ) ) {
        checkIfTransactionInProgress( event.getSession() );
        if ( yourFieldStatusMatchesAuditCriteria( event ) ) {
          return super.onPreUpdate( event );
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

If you can find all the other listener classes but you aren't able to find the `pre-update` handler, chances are perhaps you're using an older version of Envers.  It's worth noting that the `pre-update` event listener was added in Hibernate Envers recently, version 5.2.7 to be exact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You were absolutely right about the hibernate version.